# New line in django templates

Tags: django

When I use the following:

```
<html>
{% block head %}
<title>Hello</title>
{% endblock %}
```

The output in the HTML document is:

```
<html>
--- empty line ---
<title>Hello</title>
```

How can I avoid this empty line?
I can use:

```
<html>
{% block head %}<title>Hello</title>
{% endblock %}
```

but that is ugly...

Thanks,

Joel

Answer (score 5):

If you are concerned about saving space/kbytes you can use [the `{% spaceless %}` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#spaceless) to get get rid of all the empty spaces between html tags. This is generally good practice. So put `{% spaceless %}` at the very top of your base.html and `{% endspaceless %}` at the very end

If you are worried about the asthetics of your code, there's not much you can do!

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you :P. any way to do that within the tag? I want to eliminate all the extra whitespace within the for loop but spaceless apparently only does it outside the tags

Answer (score 0):

`{% spaceless %}`  ?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#spaceless